# Angular Material how to align layout center

Tags: css, angularjs, typescript, angular-material, material-design

I have this straight out of angular material website, because im having a lot of trouble with angular material flex layout.

According to the doc about [layout container](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container)
Items arranged in a row. max-height = 100% and max-width is the width of the items in the container.

I tried the example provide at the doc [page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment)

```
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-cloak>

<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>

</div>
```

my content is suppose to align vertically and horizontally at the center. but instead my content is aligning horizontally but not vertically.

I have the code example [here](http://codepen.io/candoa/pen/ggPoKe?editors=1010#0)

Comment: The problem is the outer div has no fix width and height give it 100% width and height.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div layout-fill ng-app="myapp" ng-cloak>

<div layout="row" layout-fill layout-align="center center">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>

</div>
```

please apply layout-fill on the containers that require to take up all the space